# Excel - Extract data into new workbook based on a column values and the new work books should have various sheets based on the another column values

Tags: excel, vba

In my Work book,

The first 5 rows are my sheet header.
6th row is my table header having 10 columns. I have to create a new workbook based on the unique values in column D.

The new work books should have Sheet header and Table values based on the filter from column D.

Column D has "Kitchen", "Living Room", "Bed Room" & "Toilet"
Column B has "Panel Type A", "Panel Type B", "Panel Type c" & "Panel Type D"

I need new work books named "Kitchen", "Living Room", "Bed Room" & "Toilet"

Each work book 
first sheet should have "Sheet Header" & Visible Table Values filtered by column D and sort by Column B. 
Second Sheet should have "Sheet header" & visible table values filter by column B
Third sheet should have Sheet headed & visible table values filtered by column C

And so on....

Is there a Excel macro to do this?

I used some codes from website and did some small changes. It works well, but I am unable to copy the Sheet header (First 5 lines) to my new works. can any one please help.

Below is my code

```
Sub Copy_To_Workbooks()
    Dim My_Range As Range
    Dim copyRange As Range
    Dim FieldNum As Long
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim foldername As String
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim CCount As Long
    Dim WSNew As Worksheet
    Dim ErrNum As Long

    'Set filter range on ActiveSheet: A1 is the top left cell of your filter range
    'and the header of the first column, D is the last column in the filter range.
    'You can also add the sheet name to the code like this :
    'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D" & LastRow(Worksheets("Sheet1")))
    'No need that the sheet is active then when you run the macro when you use this.
    'Set My_Range = Range("A1:D" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))
    Set My_Range = Range("A6:J" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))
    My_Range.Parent.Select

    If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Or _
       My_Range.Parent.ProtectContents = True Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, not working when the workbook or worksheet is protected", _
               vbOKOnly, "Copy to new workbook"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'This example filters on the first column in the range(change the field if needed)
    'In this case the range starts in A so Field:=1 is column A, 2 = column B, ......
    FieldNum = 4

    'Turn off AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    'Set the file extension/format
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        'You use Excel 97-2003
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        'You use Excel 2007-2013
        If ActiveWorkbook.FileFormat = 56 Then
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
        Else
            FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
        End If
    End If

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    'Delete the sheet RDBLogSheet if it exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("RDBLogSheet").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Add worksheet to copy/Paste the unique list
    Set ws2 = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    ws2.Name = "RDBLogSheet"

    'Fill in the path\folder where you want the new folder with the files
    'you can use also this "C:\Users\Ron\test"
    MyPath = Application.DefaultFilePath

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'Create folder for the new files
    foldername = MyPath & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss") & "\"
    MkDir foldername

    With ws2
        'first we copy the Unique data from the filter field to ws2
        My_Range.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
                Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                CopyToRange:=.Range("A3"), Unique:=True
        'My_Range.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
                Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                CopyToRange:=.Range("F6"), Unique:=True

        'loop through the unique list in ws2 and filter/copy to a new sheet
        Lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each cell In .Range("A4:A" & Lrow)

            'Filter the range
            My_Range.AutoFilter field:=FieldNum, Criteria1:="=" & _
             Replace(Replace(Replace(cell.Value, "~", "~~"), "*", "~*"), "?", "~?")

            'Check if there are no more then 8192 areas(limit of areas)
            CCount = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            CCount = My_Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) _
                     .Areas(1).Cells.Count
            On Error GoTo 0
            If CCount = 0 Then
                MsgBox "There are more than 8192 areas for the value : " & cell.Value _
                     & vbNewLine & "It is not possible to copy the visible data." _
                     & vbNewLine & "Tip: Sort your data before you use this macro.", _
                       vbOKOnly, "Split in worksheets"
            Else
                'Add new workbook with one sheet
                Set WSNew = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)

                'Copy/paste the visible data to the new workbook
                'copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                My_Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                With WSNew.Range("A6")
                    ' Paste:=8 will copy the columnwidth in Excel 2000 and higher
                    ' Remove this line if you use Excel 97
                    .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    .Select
                    Click
                End With

                'Save the file in the new folder and close it
                On Error Resume Next
                WSNew.Parent.SaveAs foldername & _
                                    cell.Value & FileExtStr, FileFormatNum
                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    ErrNum = ErrNum + 1

                    WSNew.Parent.SaveAs foldername & _
                     "Error_" & Format(ErrNum, "0000") & FileExtStr, FileFormatNum

                    .Cells(cell.Row, "B").Formula = "=Hyperlink(""" & foldername & _
                      "Error_" & Format(ErrNum, "0000") & FileExtStr & """)"

                    .Cells(cell.Row, "A").Interior.Color = vbRed
                Else
                    .Cells(cell.Row, "B").Formula = _
                    "=Hyperlink(""" & foldername & cell.Value & FileExtStr & """)"
                End If

                WSNew.Parent.Close False
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If

            'Show all the data in the range
            My_Range.AutoFilter field:=FieldNum

        Next cell
        .Cells(1, "A").Value = "Red cell: can't use the Unique name as file name"
        .Cells(1, "B").Value = "Created Files (Click on the link to open a file)"
        .Cells(3, "A").Value = "Unique Values"
        .Cells(3, "B").Value = "Full Path and File name"
        .Cells(3, "A").Font.Bold = True
        .Cells(3, "B").Font.Bold = True
        .Columns("A:B").AutoFit

    End With

    'Turn off AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    If ErrNum > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Rename every WorkSheet name that start with ""Error_"" manually" _
             & vbNewLine & "There are characters in the name that are not allowed" _
             & vbNewLine & "in a sheet name or the worksheet already exist."
    End If

    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    My_Range.Parent.Select
    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    ws2.Select
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With

End Sub

Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function Click()
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vcol, i As Integer
    Dim icol As Long
    Dim myarr As Variant
    Dim title As String
    Dim copystart As Integer
    Dim x As Long
    vcol = 2 ' based on which column the split sheet to be created
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' Delet all sheet except sheet name BOM
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If xWs.Name <> "Sheet1" And xWs.Name <> "ESTIMATION SUMMARY" And xWs.Name <> "Sheet Metal Std" Then
            xWs.Delete
        End If
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ' End of delete sheet

    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row 'Returns last row
    title = "A6:O6" ' Sets the title range
    copystart = 1 ' in BOM sheet from where  to copy
    icol = ws.Columns.Count ' End last column in BOM sheet 16384
    ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique" ' Set text "Unique at 16384th column
    ' Find number of varient on column 5
    For i = 7 To lr
        On Error Resume Next
                If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
         ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
        End If
    Next
    'End of "Find number of varient on column 5"
    myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
    ws.Columns(icol).Clear

    'Creating new Sheet based on column 5 and copy those values in that sheet
    For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
        ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
        If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
         Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
        Else
            Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        End If
        ws.Range("A" & copystart & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
        Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
        'x = Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row 'Returns last row
    Next
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Activate
    ' End
End Function
```

Comment: I found some programs in your website and other pages. I did some small changes and it worked well except some issues. I am unable to find a way to copy the Sheet header (First 5 lines) to new work book. Below the code I have used. can any one help me on this

Comment: Hello Dasarathan Sampath, welcome to SO. Your code is very long, can't you simplify it and show us exactly where is the problem?

Comment: Hello Panda, I missed your message, Sorry. My issue got resolved. Thanks for your time.